# Trouble with callback in Entry widget Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have the following code (only sections of it) for getting the entries in 4 Entry boxes I have created. However I have two niggles:

- When I type into each box, it types the same thing and I wish to type different numbers and assign all of them to separate variables.
- Is there any way of producing 4 boxes in a loop and fewer lines than this?

  number = StringVar()
  def numberwritten(*args):
      number.trace("w", numberwritten)
      fg = number.get()
      print fg

  ## In separate definition def ChoiceBox(choice): (not full code under this def)

  def ChoiceBox(choice):
          i = [0, 1, 2, 3]

  ```
      for i in i:
          choice_title = Label(choice_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
          choice_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

      box1 = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0, textvariable=number)
      box1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
      box2 = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0, textvariable=number)
      box2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
      box3 = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0, textvariable=number)
      box3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
      box4 = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0, textvariable=number)
      box4.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
  ```

UPDATE/EDIT:

This is the section of code I have and cannot figure out what's going wrong with it at the end as I'm receiving syntax errors:

```
def numberwritten(number):
    fg = number.get()
    print fg

numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(4) ] #Name available in global scope. 
for i in numbers: 
    i.trace('w',lambda n=i: numberwritten(n) ) 


def ChoiceBox(choice):


    column = 0
    if choice == "Fixed":
        choice_frame.grid_forget()      
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "No optimisation, value fixed.")
    elif choice == "List":

        for i in xrange(4): 
            choice_title = Label(choice_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0) 
        choice_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1) 
        boxes=[] 

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Please fill in list values.")


    elif choice == "Interval" or "Optimisation":
        i = [0, 1]
        choice_title1 = Label(choice_frame, text='Min Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        choice_title1.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="N S E W", padx=1, pady=1)
        choice_title2 = Label(choice_frame, text='Max Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        choice_title2.grid(row=0, column=column+1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

        boxes=[]

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Enter Min/Max values.")

for i in xrange(4): 
        box=Entry(choice_frame,bg='white',borderwidth=0,textvariable=numbers[i]) 
        box.grid(row=1,column=i, sticky='ew', padx=1, pady=1 
        boxes.append(box)
    box1,box2,box3,box4=boxes
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation on this?  It's hard to see what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise, fixed now. The part from i onwards is usually in a separate function of it's own but the indentation within that part is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please stop using:

```
i=[1,2,3,4]
for i in i:
    ...
```

Use:

```
for i in (1,2,3,4):
    ...
```

instead.

Or better:

```
for i in xrange(1,5): #range in python3.x
    ...
```

Now, creating the stuff in the loop is easy:

```
strvars=[]
boxes=[]
for i in xrange(1,5):
    svar=StringVar()
    box=Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0, textvariable=svar)
    box.grid(row=1, column=i-1, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
    svar.trace('w',numberwritten)
    #If you want to pass the box associated with the stringvar, you can do this:
    #svar.trace('w',lambda a,b,c,box=box : numberwritten(box)) #box.get() get's the contents of an Entry too!
    strvars.append(svar)
    boxes.append(box)

number1,number2,number3,number4=strvars  #unpack stringvars 
box1,box2,box3,box4=boxes   #unpack boxes
```

You need a distinct `StringVar` for each box.  The unpacking only works if you know how many items there are in the lists holding the StringVars and Entry boxes.  Otherwise, you can get references to the box/variable you want by `boxes[0]` and `strvars[0]` for example.

**EDIT**

Something like this should work...

```
def numberwritten(number):
    fg = number.get()
    print fg 

numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(4) ]  #Name available in global scope.
for i in numbers:
    i.trace('w',lambda a,b,c,n=i: numberwritten(n) )

# In separate definition def ChoiceBox(choice): (not full code under this def)
def ChoiceBox(choice):  

    for i in xrange(4):
        choice_title = Label(choice_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        choice_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

    boxes=[]
    for i in xrange(4):
        box=Entry(choice_frame,bg='white',borderwidth=0,textvariable=numbers[i])
        box.grid(row=1,column=i, sticky='ew', padx=1, pady=1
        boxes.append(box)

    box1,box2,box3,box4=boxes
```

As an aside, why are you using `width=0` everywhere?  an Entry/Label with no width is pretty much useless.

Comment: Thank you! I however have the problem where I need to define strvars in another definition (as the part from i in xrange onwards is in another definition in my code). How would I do this?

Comment: @user2063 -- Just do it in a separate loop creating a list of `strvars`.  Then in your Entry constructor, use `textvariable=strvars[i]`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand. I thought before to do this I had to use classes? How would I do it without using a class?

Comment: I have added a comment in my code. Is there a way of passing the strvars outside the ChoiceBox def to be used in the numberwritten def?

Comment: @user2063 -- I don't see any ChoiceBox in your code.  I also don't see any comments ...

Comment: I added the comment but now have added in the def itself.

Comment: @user2063 -- I've edited.  Hopefully that will help solve your problem.  If not, I suggest you open another question.

Comment: Is there an indentation error in this? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13113/discussion-between-user2063-and-mgilson)

Comment: @user2063 -- There was an indentation error.  (It looked OK in the editor, but there was a spaces vs. tabs error -- I should never try to code in the SO entry window.)

Comment: Ok got it working (I was missing a end bracket in my code..!). In my code above (update) how would I accept either the 4 or 2 values? I'm receiving an error now of lambda() takes at most 1 argument (3 given).

Comment: @user2063 -- try `i.trace('w',lambda a,b,c,n=i: numberwritten(n) )`  (I've edited).  Apparently the callback passed to `trace` takes 3 arguments, although I haven't been able to find that documented anywhere.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this question when it's been answered but I was wondering if there was a way to (if I managed to find the number of boxes through a calculation) if I can return 'n' number of values through the same function? If I find the number I will know how many but won't be able to say 'number1, number2' etc. Is there a way to say for i in range(number that I find out): do number[i] = numbers or something similar?

Comment: @user2063 -- yes, that's exactly how the `boxes` variable above will work (If I understand you correctly)

Answer (score 1):

The `StringVar` is a Model for the `Entry` (and a few other things in Tkinter). You've given each `Entry` instance a reference to the same `StringVar` object, so naturally they share the model and thus show the same contents. You'll need to make four different `StringVar` objects, one for each `Entry`. (Those, you'll create in a loop that is iterating over the collection of `StringVar`s…)